# how to solve ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

When I try to fit a model

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(train_features, y)
```

I get

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'
```

Comment: hey there, it may be the issue with the data, please give more information

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback) in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: machine learning works on numbers - and it seems you have string `RL` in your data - and you have to convert it to number too.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have an attribute with `str` value and `RandomForestRegressor` takes as input numeric values only.

You can solve this using the following from sklearn:

1. [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)
2. [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)
3. [Binarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Binarizer.html)

Comment: when i put this code :

for label, content in train_features.items():
    if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(content):
            print(label)

i got nothing, that mean there is no string value, right?